# Monopoly - Passing Go Backwards

Tags: monopoly

I played Monopoly, and I passed Go, and landed on the Community Chest 2 spaces after the Go space. I picked up the "Pay $10, or draw a Chance Card". I drew a Chance card and I got "Go back three spaces."

Now, since I passed Go backwards, do I get $-200 (i.e., pay $200), and/or do I get another $200 the next turn when I pass Go forwards again?